# Applying IPSet in Lede

Tags: iptables, openwrt, dnsmasq

I have been having trouble setting ipset based on host address. Here are the steps I followed with little success recently:
1. Apply list of host to /etc/dnsmasq.conf like this

```
ipset=/somehost.com/myipset
```

2. Created ipset using

```
ipset -n myipset hash:ip (also tried with hash:net)
```

3.May be the ipsets are getting created, I do not know how to validate this. However when i run

```
ipset list myipset
Name: myipset
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 4
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 88
References: 0
Members:
```

Members being blank and Reference being '0' seems to indicate that there are no ipsets being formed.

*What I have done already:*

1. Saved ipset creation in a startup script to ensure the ipset is created on boot-up
2. Tried restarting dnsmasq followed by firewall
3. Tried booting up the router.
4. Installed dnsmasq-full, ipset packages additionally in LEDE

I do remember this reference going up in Lede v17.01.3, now I use 17.01.4.  I do not recollect what I did differently to make this reference reflect correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the default `dnsmasq` package on LEDE doesn't provide ipset extenstion. You have to use the package `dnsmasq-full` instead.

You have to create your ipset before a query is made, idealy before dnsmasq is started.

```
# ipset -N myipset hash:ip
```

Dnsmasq will fill myipset when you make a DNS query on facebook.com (or a subdomain), you have to add this command on your /etc/dnsmasq.conf :

```
ipset=/.facebook.com/myipset
```

You need to restart dnsmasq at this point, then this simple command is enough to fill your ipset

```
# ping facebook.com
```

on either the router (provided that you keep 127.0.0.1 as a nameserver on the router /etc/resolv.conf) or on a client of the router (that uses the router as a DNS of course).

Alternatively, you can do this command on the router, it will give you the address(es) given by dnsmasq:

```
# nslookup facebook.com 127.0.0.1
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:      facebook.com
Address 1: 157.240.1.35
Address 2: 2a03:2880:f129:83:face:b00c::25de
```

After that dnsmasq will fill your ipset:

```
# ipset -L myipset
Name: whitelist_domain
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 4
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 100
References: 2
Members:
157.240.1.35
```

Comment: I did ping the host and even accessed it via browser, but the references/member never get incremented. Did all that you have mentioned as indicated in my post. Also is there a way to check if the packets have ipset assigned to them? other than ipset -L to check the references/members?

Comment: Nop, I've modified the command results. the references are increased when you use your ipset on a iptables : `iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set myipset dst -j ACCEPT`. As far as I know you can't count the number of matches of a member, but the iptables rule count is increased when the ipset of the rule is matched. If the members aren't increases it's probably that the dns query didn't reach dnsmasq, or that dnsmasq doesn't understant the ipset request. When you do `dnsmasq --version` do you see "ipset" in the "Compile time options:" ?